# Multiply 2 numbers which have maximum 50 digits

Tags: c++

could anyone check my multiplicate function and help me to fix the "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'operation' was corrupted."

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 1000

int checkinput(char element[])
{
    int check = 1;
    if (strlen(element) >= 51)
    {
        check = 0;
        printf("\nVariable can not contain more than 50 character!");
        return check;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(element) - 1; i++)
    {
        if (element[i] <= 47 || element[i] >= 58)
        {
            check = 0;
            printf("\nThe entered variable contain character(s) different from set (0...9)!");
            return check;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
int checkoperation(char OPERATION[])
{
    int check = 0;
    if (strlen(OPERATION) >= 2)
    {
        printf("\nThe entered operation is not accepted!");
        return check;
    }
    char op = OPERATION[0];
    if (op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')
    {
        check = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        check = 0;
        printf("\nThe entered operation is not accepted!");
    }
    return check;
}
void getinput(char value1[], char value2[], char Operation[])
{
    int checkvalue1;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the first variable: ");
        gets(value1);
        checkvalue1 = checkinput(value1);
    } while (checkvalue1 == 0);
    int check_operation;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the operation: ");
        gets(Operation);
        check_operation = checkoperation(Operation);
    } while (check_operation == 0);
    int checkvalue2;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the second variable: ");
        gets(value2);
        checkvalue2 = checkinput(value2);
    } while (checkvalue2 == 0);
}
void addelement(char element[], int position, char add)
{
    for (int i = strlen(element); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        element[i + 1] = element[i];
    }
    element[position] = add;
    element[strlen(element) + 1] = '\0';
}
void synchronizeinputs(char varia1[], char varia2[])
{
    int check;
    strlen(varia1) > strlen(varia2) ? check = 1 : check = 0;
    if (check == 1)
    {
        int lenght1 = strlen(varia1) - strlen(varia2);
        for (int i = 1; i <= lenght1 ; i++)
        {
            addelement(varia2, 0, '0');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int lenght2 = strlen(varia2) - strlen(varia1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= lenght2 ; i++)
        {
            addelement(varia1, 0, '0');
        }
    }
}
void plus( char number1[], char number2[], char Result[])
{
    int remain = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(number1) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (remain == 1)
        {
            remain = 0;
            Result[strlen(number1) - 1 - i] = ((number1[i] - 48) + (number2[i] - 48) + 1) % 10 + 48;
            if ((((number1[i] - 48) + (number2[i] - 48) + 1) / 10) == 1)
            {
                remain = 1;
            }
            continue;
        }
        Result[strlen(number1) - 1 - i] = ((number1[i] - 48) + (number2[i] - 48)) % 10 + 48;
        if((((number1[i] - 48) + (number2[i] - 48)) / 10)  == 1)
        { 
            remain = 1;
        }
    }
    if (remain == 1)
    {
        Result[strlen(number1)] = '1';
        Result[strlen(number1) + 1] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        Result[strlen(number1)] = '\0';
    }
    strrev(Result);
}
void minusinside(char number1[], char number2[], char Result[])
{
    int remain = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(number1) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (remain == 0)
        {
            // if variable 1 smaller than variable 2, then add variable 1 10 units.
            if (number1[i] < number2[i])
            {
                number1[i] += 10;
                remain = 1;
            }
            Result[strlen(number1) - 1 - i] = (number1[i] - 48) - (number2[i] - 48) + 48;
        }
        else
        {
            // if variable 1 smaller than variable 2 plus 1 unit, then add variable 1 10 units.
            if (number1[i] < number2[i] + 1)
            {
                number1[i] += 10;
                remain = 1;
            }
            else
                remain = 0;
            Result[strlen(number1) - 1 - i] = (number1[i] - 48) - (number2[i] - 47) + 48;
        }
    }
    Result[strlen(number1)] = '\0';
    strrev(Result);
}
void minus(char number1[], char number2[], char* Result)
{
    int check = 1;
    int i = 0;
    // compare to consider which variable is greater than the other.
    do
    {
        if (number1[i] > number2[i])
        {
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if (number1[i] < number2[i])
        {
            check = 0;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    } while (number1[i] == number2[i] && i <= strlen(number1));
    // if check = 1, then execute "minusinside" regularly
    if (check == 1)
        minusinside(number1, number2, Result);
    // if check = 0, then execute "minusinside" and insert a "-" in the firt posstion of "Result"
    else
    {
        minusinside(number2, number1, Result);
        addelement(Result, 0, '-');
    }
}
void multiplicate(char number1[], char number2[], char Result[])
{
    char re[MAX];
    int count0 = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(number1) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int remain = 0;
        for (int j = strlen(number1) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            re[strlen(number1) - 1 - j] = ((number1[i] - 48) * (number2[j] - 48) + remain) % 10 + 48;
            remain = ((number1[i] - 48) * (number2[j] - 48) + remain) / 10;
        }
        re[strlen(number1)] = remain + 48;
        re[strlen(number1) + 1] = '\0';
        for (int k = 1; k <= count0; k++)
        {
            addelement(re, 0, '0');
        }
        char re2[MAX];
        for (int u = strlen(re) - 1; u >= 0; u--)
        {
            re2[strlen(re) - 1 - u] = re[u];
        }
        re2[strlen(re)] = '\0';
        char re3[MAX];
        for (int q = 0; q <= strlen(Result) - 1; q++)
        {
            re3[q] = Result[q];
        }
        re3[strlen(Result)] = '\0';
        synchronizeinputs(re2, re3);
        plus(re3, re2, Result);
        count0++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char variable1[MAX], variable2[MAX], operation[MAX];
    char RESULT[] = "0";
    getinput(variable1, variable2, operation);
    synchronizeinputs(variable1, variable2);
    //plus(variable1, variable2, RESULT);
    //minus(variable1, variable2, RESULT);
    multiplicate(variable1, variable2, RESULT);
    printf("\nResult is: %s", RESULT);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
char RESULT[] = "0";
```

you define result as an array capable of holding strings of length 1 at most. It is the same as

```
char RESULT[2] = "0";
```

Maybe you want the array to be capable of holding strings large enough for the number of digits in the multiplication of 2 50-digit numbers?

```
char RESULT[50+50+1] = "0";
```

Comment: Oh, using ALLCAPS for such an important variable as `RESULT` is, arguably, a bad idea.

Comment: I think that I did it because the MAX is assigned to 1000

Comment: @HuyLieuxuon in that case `char RESULT[MAX+MAX-1] = "0";` or just be generous and use `char RESULT[MAX+MAX] = "0";`

Comment: You drfined the macro `MAX`, but, somehow (lack of attention perhaps?) failed to use it when defining `RESULT`.